# How to auto download file video in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try make an auto download a video when function download is run.
I'm try using saveAs(fileSaver.js) but getting error

> Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found
>   that matched the signature provided.

any one can help.

```
$scope.download = function(){
        var fd = new FormData();
        angular.forEach($scope.files, function(video){
            fd.append('video', video);
        });

        var request = $http({
            method : 'POST',
            url: xxxx + 'video/upload?start=' + $scope.start + '&end=' + $scope.end,
            data : fd,
            transformRequest:angular.identity,
            headers:{'Content-Type':undefined}
        });
        request.then(function(response){
            saveAs(response , 'video.mp4');
            $scope.isProcessing = false;
        }, function(error){
            $scope.isProcessing = false;
        });
    }
```

In serve side I using flask will return as a below :

```
return send_file(app.root_path + '/' + app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] + '/uploadV/dd.mp4', as_attachment=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **[angular-file-saver](https://github.com/alferov/angular-file-saver)** you need to create a blob by using `arraybuffer` response type:

```
$scope.download = function(){

    var fd = new FormData();
    angular.forEach($scope.files, function(video){
        fd.append('video', video);
    });

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: xxxx + 'video/upload?start=' + $scope.start + '&end=' + $scope.end,
        data: fd,
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        responseType: 'arraybuffer',
        transformResponse: function (data) {
            var video;
            if (data) {
                video = new Blob([data], {
                    type: 'video/mp4'
                });
            }
            return {
                response: video
            };
        },
    }).then(function(file){
        saveAs(file.response, 'video.mp4');
        $scope.isProcessing = false;
    }, function(error){
        $scope.isProcessing = false;
    });
};
```

Comment: I follow your code, I got error. net:: ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED. I already add ngFileSaver in my module.
Have other method upload a video that you know? @lin

Comment: @HannahDelisa Are you sure your API endpoint with method `POST` is accessable -> `xxxx + 'video/upload?start=' + $scope.start + '&end=' + $scope.end` ?

Comment: That problem at python code. Now every think fine , only part saveAs(file.response, 'video.mp4'); . Error show TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined at new FileSaver. Thanks for help @lin

Comment: did you know a method other than this method?

Comment: @HannahDelisa could you mark this answer as right? (the grey hook near the upvote answer buttons)! Thanks!

Comment: @HannahDelisa if you are looking for a different solution please open a new question. Please don't forget to mark right answers (the grey hook near the answer upvote buttons). If you open a new question just link it here.